# Adolf Hitler's DNA samples and the consequences

Tags: hitler

Are there any known DNA samples of Adolf Hitler? What could possibly happen if, given inevitable global population's DNA collection and serialization, somebody turns out to be his descendant?

Comment: Hitler had no children so you're asking for a counterfactual, as well as a hypothetical.

Comment: Also, what does it matter if there is an actual descendant? There are many descendants of Genghis Khan and nobody cares at all; there are descendants of other high-ranking Nazi leaders and many of them publicly condemn their parents.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is off-topic. Please check the [faq] and [help].

Comment: Note that this is a website for asking *History* questions. Any question you ask that is phrased using future tense ("could happen") is by definition off-topic.

Comment: "Keep you enemies close, and possible genetic clones of Adolf Hitler closer" - Malory Archer

Answer (score 2):

Jean-Mare Loret (1918-1985) claimed he was Hitler's illegitimate child.  He had 9 children, some of whom may still be alive and/or have descendants.

Loret was bothered by reporters, etc., but so far as I know didn't get many death threats.

As far as I heard, the results of genetic testing were inconclusive, showing that Loret could be Hitler's son but didn't have to be.

I'm sure those more familiar with this story can say more about it.